# octave 5.2 on ubuntu 18.04: print -dpng does not work

Tags: png, octave, ghostscript

I installed on Ubuntu 18.04 octave 5.2 using snap.
Now I have octave 5.2.
There is an issue.
If I try to print a figure (out of a plot) using

```
print -dpng figure.png
```

I obtain this error message:

```
warning: print.m: Ghostscript binary is not available. Only eps output is possible
```

If I execute the command

```
which ghostscript
```

the answer is

```
/usr/bin/ghostscript.
```

Please: could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: It may be something to do with how octave was compiled (e.g. without ghostscript support). I would highly recommend you to compile octave from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to the current LTS version 20.04 and install Octave in the same version 5.2 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/octave) via the normal (not snap) package management using `apt install octave` and the package management system automatically deals with the dependencies.